# How to exclude .jar dependency in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I build a project which consists of some other projects. In first project I have next dependency:

```
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

Which is old version of Google services API. In other project I use other the latest Google API

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
```

As a result if I try to compile this projects as one, I get error about library conflict. Tell me please, how can I solve this problem?

The problem is that I get next conflict when launching built app:

```
error: cannot find symbol method getMapAsync(<anonymous OnMapReadyCallback>)
```

It seems that when compilation finishes and app launches, for unknown reasons it tries to take old api (where api should be version 8.3.0) instead of new.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the conflict is, but this is how you exclude dependencies:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'){
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

(a made up example)